# Como fazer para mudar a URL de uma imagem quando a resolução for abaixo de 767px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho um site o qual ele é responsivo.

O problema é que o header possui um background azul e uma logomarca branca. Quando a resolução fica abaixo de 767px ele muda o menu.

Imagens:

*Como está no computador:*
[image]

*Como está no tablet/celular:*
[image]

***Como tem que ficar no tablet/celular:***

[image]

O que quero é que quando a resolução for abaixo de 767px ela mude para outra imagem.

Ex:

`<img src="logo-branca.png" />`

Quando a resolução for abaixo de 767px:

`<img src="logo-azul.png" />`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando puro **Javascript** podemos verificar a propriedade `window.innerWidth` do objeto global, que representa a largura da janela do navegador em pixels.

```
<img id="logo" src="branca" />   

<script>
function updateLogo() {
    var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
    if(window.innerWidth < 767) { // verifica a largura da janela do navegador
        logo.src = "logo-azul.png";
    } else {
        logo.src = "logo-branca.png";
    }
}

updateLogo(); // faz o primeiro ajuste

window.addEventListener("resize", updateLogo); // atualiza o logo ao redimensionar a tela
</script>
```

Também é possível através de **CSS Media Queries** utilizando uma propriedade background para o div onde o logo estará contido e alterando a imagem de background de acordo com a resolução desejada:

```
<style>
#logo {
    background: url('logo-azul.png') no-repeat;
    width: 200px; /* a largura da imagem */
    height: 100px;  /* a altura da imagem */
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
    #logo {
        background: url('logo-branca.png') no-repeat;
    }
}
</style>

<div id="logo"></div>
```

**Dê preferência para a solução em CSS** pois a solução em Javascript não funcionará se o navegador estiver com o Javascript desativado ¬¬

### Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/4adJ4/)

**[Clique aqui](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AlexandreBR/4adJ4/show/)** para visualizar em tela cheia.

OBS: Diminua a janela do navegador para visualizar as diferenças.

Comment: Olá @Gustavo Carvalho
Em CSS eu já sei, gostaria de conhecer o funcionamento com JS.
Obrigado!

Comment: Disponha @AlexandreLopes. Ficou alguma dúvida ou teve alguma dificuldade para implementar o código Javascript na sua página?

Comment: Sem nenhum problema! Obrigado! :D