# Como mudar imagem do site dependendo da resolução da tela do dispositivo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, carousel

Tenho um carrosel em Bootstrap, e estou tentando alterar as imagens dele dependendo da resolução da tela do dispositivo utilizando Javascript, mas não sei como fazer isso funcionar.

```js
var width = screen.width;
var image1 = document.getElementsById("slide1");

if (width <= 411)
  image1.src = "../Pictures/slide2.jpg";
```

```html
<img id="slide1" class="d-block w-100" src="Pictures/slide1.jpg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
```

Inseri um alert dentro do if para verificar se a estrutura de condição funcionava, e o alert apareceu como esperado. Acredito que o problema esteja na forma que eu estou tentando fazer isso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se você codificou exatamente como está postado aqui na pergunta, pode ser somente um erro de digitação: em vez de `document.getElementsById("slide1")` você deveria digitar **`document.getElementById("slide1")`**, com _Element_ no singular.

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21726/como-fazer-para-mudar-a-url-de-uma-imagem-quando-a-resolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-for-abaixo-de-767px?rq=1

Comment: Não precisa de JS: [Trocar a imagem em telas menores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244285/trocar-a-imagem-em-telas-menores)